# CxImage GIF "corrupted" on save

Tags: c++, image, gif

I have a slight problem with saving a GIF in the C++ CxImage library.
I have posted this also on the CxImage forums, but they seem rather dead, so I'm hoping to find someone on here who is using CxImage and may have encountered this issue.

I am using version 7.01 (latest).

When I save a GIF, it always shows up as 17x15 pixels, and most software cannot display this. (Internet explorer, Windows Explorer, Photoshop 7.0, Irfanview). Other software deals with this fine (MSPaint, MSOffice Photo Editor, and CxImage itself).

I have dug in deep, and have come to see that it is caused in CxImageGIF::EncodeRGB, on line 698 in ximagif.cpp:

```
const int32_t cellw = 17; // <-- This is where the dimensions shown in Win Explorer come from
const int32_t cellh = 15; // <--
CxImageGIF tmp;
for (int32_t y=0;y<head.biHeight;y+=cellh){
    for (int32_t x=0;x<head.biWidth;x+=cellw){
        if ((head.biWidth -x)<cellw) w=head.biWidth -x; else w=cellw;
        if ((head.biHeight-y)<cellh) h=head.biHeight-y; else h=cellh;

        if (w!=tmp.GetWidth() || h!=tmp.GetHeight()) tmp.Create(w,h,8);

        if (IsTransparent()){
            tmp.SetTransIndex(0);
            tmp.SetPaletteColor(0,GetTransColor());
        }

        uint8_t i;
        for (uint32_t j=0;j<h;j++){
            for (uint32_t k=0;k<w;k++){
                i=(uint8_t)(1+k+cellw*j);
                tmp.SetPaletteColor(i,GetPixelColor(x+k,head.biHeight-y-h+j));
                tmp.SetPixelIndex(k,j,tmp.GetNearestIndex(tmp.GetPaletteColor(i)));
            }
        }

        tmp.SetOffset(x,y);
        tmp.EncodeExtension(fp);
        tmp.EncodeBody(fp,true);
    }
}
```

The logical screen descriptor is set to the correct image size, but apparently, the image gets encoded in small 15x17 data blocks.

From what I understand about the GIF standard, this can be done this way, but it seems that a lot of programs don't understand this properly, and assume each block is a whole frame. Maybe I'm wrong, I just read that part about the GIF standard last night

It seems this is used for animation normally, and CxImage sets the frame time for this frame to 0 correctly. However, some programs then draw the image block by block with the default GIF timeout.

I tried tinkering with the code to make it encode each frame in one block by setting cellw and cellh to head.biWidth and head.biHeight respectively, but to no avail. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Even if you don't use CxImage, but are familiar with GIF89a, maybe you could just confirm that I am correct in my interpretation of the GIF standard?
I find it hard to believe that Microsoft and/or Adobe would not write code that would properly decode any GIF image according the the standard.
Also do I find it hard to believe that one of the best available C++ libraries for image manipulation would improperly or unusually encode a common file format like GIF.